# curl for geoserver process

Tags: xml, curl, geoserver

I all. i have the follow xml execute file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<wps:Execute xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0     http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"     xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WPS" version="1.0.0">
<ows:Identifier>gs:HelloWPS</ows:Identifier>
<wps:DataInputs>
<wps:Input>    
<ows:Identifier>Hello!!</ows:Identifier>
<wps:Data>
<wps:LiteralData>world</wps:LiteralData>
</wps:Data>
</wps:Input>
</wps:DataInputs>
<wps:ResponseForm>
<wps:RawDataOutput>
<ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
</wps:RawDataOutput>
</wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

This file named Hello.xml is saved on the Desktop.
I'm also just right connect on geoserver like administrator.
I would make this process by curl command like:
curl -H 'Content-type:xml' -XPOST --data 'C:...\Desktop\Hello.xml'

The result is following the exception:
Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@6c7e7eb8

Someone can help me? thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I am far from the utmost expert, but I was able to invoke a geoserver wps process using:

curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d@wpsreq.xml -X POST http://geoserver.local:8080/geoserver/wps

...so, note differences in my invocation: 
-Content-Type: text/xml
-Space between X and POST

...I don't know anything about process gs:HelloWPS.  This process does not seem to be among the ones distributed with geoserver/GDAL.  I'm using things like gs:GeoRectifyCoverage, etc.  You can see the installed list of usable processes in the WPS command builder app.  In geoserver, click "Demos", then "WPS Request Builder", then click the "Choose Process" dropdown to see the list of processes you can invoke.